# Google Picker API + Angular2 getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleAuthResult' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, google-picker

I'm integrating Google picker API in my application.
I'm following the official documentation [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/)

google api js i included in my index.html page as suggested by docs

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

here is my div in html page :

```
<img src="../GoogleDrive.png(click)="onApiLoad()">
```

here is my component code :

```
  onApiLoad() {
         let self = this;
         gapi.load('auth', {'callback': self.onAuthApiLoad});
         gapi.load('picker');
     }

     onAuthApiLoad() {
         let self = this;
         window.gapi.auth.authorize(                
                 {
                     'client_id': "clientid",
                     'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
                     'immediate': false
                 },
                 self.handleAuthResult);
     }

      handleAuthResult(authResult:any) {
         let self = this;
         if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
             oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
             self.createPicker(oauthToken);
         }
     }

     createPicker() {
         let self = this;
         if ( oauthToken) {
             var pickerBuilder = new google.picker.PickerBuilder();
             var picker = pickerBuilder
             .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
             .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
             .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS_VIDEOS)
             .setDeveloperKey('apikey')
             .setCallback(self.pickerCallback)
             .build();
             picker.setVisible(true);
         }
     }

     pickerCallback(data) {
         let self = this;
         if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
             var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
             self.downloadGDriveFile(doc.id , doc.name);
         }
     }

     downloadGDriveFile(fileId, name){
}
```

I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleAuthResult' of undefined.
Can anyone please help me..

Comment: i got the same issue.... what was the solution ? to "this" being not "this"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `load` method is not giving the lexical `this` inside the callback, try to bind `this` to your method:

```
gapi.load('auth', {'callback': self.onAuthApiLoad.bind(this)});
```

Comment: Got error "Cannot set property 'oauthToken' of undefined at webpackJsonp.486.AppComponent.handleAuthResult"

Comment: @RamaKrishna can't say anything without seeing the code, make a new question maybe?